# 100°C =100K = how?

Tags: temperature

I'm in first year. Our class is in lesson " Heat and Thermodynamics". While solving a numerical problem of a reversible engine he told us that 100 degree Celsius is equal to 100 kelvin. I inquired but could not get satisfactory answer. Pleas help me understand it.

**Here is the numerical, please consider it:**
A reversibe engine works between two temperatures whose difference is 100c. If it absorbs 746J of heat from the source and rejects 546J to the sink, calculate the temperature of the source and the sink.
Ans (100°C, 0°C)

Comment: This is a duplicate to nearly every question in this search:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=kelvin+celsius